# Different fonts for answers and suggested edits in the dropdown menu

Tags: bug, design

A very minor cosmetic issue: Entries in the dropdown menu (the one that opens by hovering over the user name on the top of the site) use different fonts depending on whether the entry in the reputation history is for an answer or for a suggested edit, which looks a bit odd:

[image]

Or is this a feature?